# Tail in Get-child item

Tags: powershell

Guys do you have a way to get the tail logs below is my code

`if(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt  C:\Users\va_scan\Downloads\test\ -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending| Select-Object -First 1 | select-String -Pattern "Disconnected" )`

apparently im getting tha latest logs but i only need 5 lines in the log file

Comment: im trying to put the tail logs or the totalcount but its not compatible in get-childitem

its working in get-content thout

Comment: Try `Get-Content -Tail 5 | select-String -Pattern "Disconnected"`

Comment: hi zett this one wont work i need to get the latest logs since my application produce daily logs

Comment: the problem on my code right now it gets the latest logs but its capturing my 1 day logs now i cant put the -tail since tail is only compatible in get-content so the question here is is there a way to put a tail in get-child item?

Comment: got it here's the code 

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt C:\Users\va_scan\Downloads\test\ -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending| Select-Object -First 1 | Get-Content -tail 5 | Select-String -Pattern "Disconnected"

Comment: @VidaVida Please post a proper answer below if you found a solution on your own :)